# Get readable error messages from a c++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++

Have you ever heard about a script able to make the g++ error messages more readable?

I am pretty sure I heard about it some times ago but I can't remember the name.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should add the g++ tag to your question, because errors in other compilers are clear enough.

Comment: Maybe also if you used a decent IDE, you'll see the errors linked clearly to the code that causes them (I'm talking of for example Netbeans...)

Comment: I've added the tag "g++", is that good?

Comment: @Nim, actually I use a good IDE, emacs which linked clearly to the code, but I feel stupid when I rapidly go the the faulty line because I'm not able to understand the whole error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be thinking of [STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html), which supports a variety of C++ compilers but is no longer being developed and doesn't guarantee to work with the latest versions of g++.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably not talking about this, but there is [colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html), which does make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

if you like Ruby there is **[GilCC](http://www.onlysolutionssoftware.com/gilcc/)**! It is very easy to install and use. Unlike Perl based scripts **GilCC** has statistics such as # of warnings and error and compile time. You don't have to mess with .bash files and it is cross platform as long as you can run Ruby on your machine. Since it is Ruby you can make it do different things such as trigger test automation, unit test or program external hardware.

Here is the link to the download page: http://www.onlysolutionssoftware.com/gilcc/

I would like to add that GilCC works with any GCC version. A lot of projects out there are limited to specific versions of GCC and because GilCC does not touch GCC or its settings, you are safe.

Answer (score 0):

If it's about the messages themselves (and not how to e.g. color them) I remember that in another, similar question (which I can't find at the moment) it was suggested to use [LLVM/Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) instead of GCC as it has better error messages.